# Retrieving an array from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on some mathematics research, and I'm having difficulty working my way through the c++ language.  Specifically, (and i'm not sure if this is even possible) I'd like to retrieve an array from a multi-dimensional array.  Let me clarify.  As I understand it, a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays.  I am working with a 3-D array, and what I want to do is retrieve an entire 2-D array from that 3-D array.  Here is a snippet from my code.  The first declarations are how I had it before (with 15 2-D arrays), the next declaration is how I want things to go (so that I can use a while loop to move through all my 2-D arrays checking for things as it goes).

```
    int round1[3][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
int round2[3][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 5 }, { 4, 6 } };
int round3[3][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 6 }, { 4, 5 } };
int round4[3][2] = { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
int round5[3][2] = { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 5 }, { 4, 6 } };
int round6[3][2] = { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 6 }, { 4, 5 } };
int round7[3][2] = { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 3 }, { 5, 6 } };
int round8[3][2] = { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 6 } };
int round9[3][2] = { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 6 }, { 3, 5 } };
int round10[3][2] = { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 6 } };
int round11[3][2] = { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 6 } };
int round12[3][2] = { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 6 }, { 3, 4 } };
int round13[3][2] = { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
int round14[3][2] = { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 5 } };
int round15[3][2] = { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 4 } };
int rounds[15][3][2] = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }, { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 5 }, { 4, 6 } }, { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 6 }, { 4, 5 } }, { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }, { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 5 }, { 4, 6 } }, { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 6 }, { 4, 5 } }, { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 3 }, { 5, 6 } }, { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 6 } }, { { 1, 4 }, { 2, 6 }, { 3, 5 } }, { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 6 } }, { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 6 } }, { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 6 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } }, { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 5 } }, { { 1, 6 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 4 } } };
int tourney_count = 0;
string tourney[5] = { "", "", "", "", "" };
int roundcount_a = 0;
int roundcount_b = 0;
int roundcount_c = 0;
int roundcount_d = 0;
int roundcount_e = 0;
if (is_compatible(rounds[0][][], rounds[3][][]))
    //do stuff
return 0;
```

is_compatible is a function I've defined above that basically checks to see if any two 2-D arrays contain like pairs.  My plan is to do some work with while loops (haven't quite figured it all out yet) to go through my 3-D array and move from one to the next checking to see which ones are compatible, and then moving on to a third array.  That's about it.

If anyone has any better ideas on how to go about something like this (not using arrays in arrays in arrays), then I would be happy to hear you out.  However, I'd really just like to know if I can do what i'm trying to do and return one of these 2-D arrays from a 3-D array.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `if (is_compatible(rounds[0], rounds[3]))`.

Comment: Thanks very much.  As I assumed, that was a pretty easy fix, just tough to find the solution.

Comment: @user3440448 A "multi-dimensional" array is actually a 1-D array where the element type is another array. Bearing this in mind, it is clear that `rounds[0]` denotes the "2-D" array, and also that `rounds[0][0]` denotes a 1-D array.

Comment: Note that C-style arrays are pretty grotty to work with in C++; consider at least using `std::array<>` which has proper value semantics.